# Grundgesetz zitieren?

Tags: quotes

In einem Deutschaufsatz (erörternde textbasierte Argumentation) habe ich folgendes geschrieben:

> Diese grundlegende Idee ist sogar im deutschen Grundgesetz, Artikel 2, festgehalten: 
>       „Jeder hat das Recht auf die freie Entfaltung seiner Persönlichkeit […].“

Meine Deutschlehrerin hat an den Rand geschrieben:

> [fehlt] Woher zitiert?

Meiner Meinung nach ist die Angabe des Artikels im Gesetz Angabe genug.

**Frage:** Ist bei Zitaten von Gesetzen eine Quellenangabe anders als ich sie bereits gemacht habe nötig?

Comment: Das ist ein Zitat und als solches korrekt angegeben ô.o

Comment: Bezieht sich bei einer Erörterung allerdings auf einen "Text ausserhalb des Textes" - Das dürfte der Grund für die Anmerkung sein. Allerdings darf man es mMn als bekannt voraussetzen, das das da steht.

Comment: Ich kaufe noch ein "s" nach...

Comment: @tofro: Kleiner Trick: Wenn Dein Kommentar noch keine Reaktion hervorgerufen hat, einfach kopieren, Kopie korrigieren, neu posten und alten Kommentar löschen. Das S gibt es dann umsonst.

Comment: Die Frage hat mit Deutscher Sprache, auch wenn sie aus dem Deutschunterricht kommt, nichts zu tun.

Comment: +1, weil es gute Frage ist. VtC, weil es wirklich offtopic ist. Es tut mir leid so.

Comment: Offenlassen, weil es mE um Zitierstil im Deutschen geht.

Comment: Ich betrachte die Frage auch als off-topic, weil es um die Beurteilung von lokalen Regeln zum Zitieren geht. Die beste Antwort dafür kann dir sicher deine Lehrerin liefern. Bemerkung: Die bisherigen close-votes mit "...only requires expertise of a language other than german..." sind m.A. nach hier Unsinn.

Comment: Korrekte Zitiertechniken sind inherenter Teil einer guten Schreibe, die wiederum sprachabhängig und wie hier sogar regionalisiert sein kann. Das ist sowas von on-topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aus dem Fließtext ist klar ersichtlich, woher das Zitat stammt. Daher verwundert mich die Randnotiz deiner Lehrerin.

Möglicherweise habt ihr im Unterricht aber bestimmte Formen des Zitierens gelernt, die ihr hier anwenden solltet. So ist es in geisteswissenschaftlichen Arbeiten oftmals vorgeschrieben, dass der Verweis auf die Quelle in Klammern hinter dem Zitat stehen muss. In naturwissenschaftlichen und technischen Publikationen wird oft verlangt, dass dem Zitat eine laufende Nummer in eckigen Klammern folgt, wobei die Nummer auf einen Eintrag in einer Liste im Anhang des Dokuments verweist, wo dann die entsprechende Quelle angeführt ist. Es gibt viele verschiedene Regeln, wie in wissenschaftlichen Texten zu zitieren ist.

Ob deine Lehrerin auf einer bestimmten formalen Form des Zitieren besteht, kann ich aus der Ferne nicht beurteilen.

Comment: Ja, wir haben solche Formen gelernt, aber die Randbemerkung "*woher* zitiert" passt meiner Meinung nach wohl eher nicht zu einer Bemängelung, dass ich diese Form nicht angewendet habe, oder?

Comment: @palsch: Nein, die Bemerkung passt schon. Es fehlt der formal korrekte Hinweis auf die Quelle. Wenn ein bestimmter Formalismus verlangt wird, und du eine Doktorarbeit oder einen Artikel für eine Fachzeitschrift abgibst, worin du so zitierst wie du es getan hast, dann wird deine Arbeit zurückgewiesen. Hier geht es unter anderem auch darum, dass automatische Plagiats-Scanner dein Werk analysieren, und ohne formal korrekte Zitats-Angabe würde der Auszug aus dem Grundgesetz von der Software als Plagiat bewertet werden.

Comment: Ich glaube kaum, dass meine Lehrerin einen Plagiats-Scanner verwendet, trotzdem danke. ;-)

Comment: In Schul-Erörterungen wird oft verlangt, dass man nur aus dem tatsächlich erörterten Text zitiert (Ich gehe davon aus, dass es sich um eine textbasierte Erörterung gehandelt hat). Da normalerweise keine Hilfsmittel verwendet werden dürfen, ist das dort auch naheliegend. Von daher scheint die Anmerkung eher auf "Wo hast du/haben Sie das im vorgelegten Text gefunden?" zu beziehen und es handelt sich eher um eine rhetorische Frage.

Comment: @tofro Grundlage für alternative Antwort ;)

Comment: @Jan Mein Kommentar ist eine *Mutmaßung* - Da mache ich ungern eine Antwort draus.

Answer (score 1):

Noch eine juristische Kleinkariertheit:
Das Zitat ist richtig, aber unvollständig. Ganz genaue Zitierweisen wären "Artikel 2 Absatz 1 Satz 1 des Grundgesetzes" (lang) und "Art. 2 I 1 GG" (kurz).

Das Bundesministerium veröffentlicht zu dem Thema das [Handbuch der Rechtsförmlichkeit](http://hdr.bmj.de/vorwort.html).